# Should titles be included in LinkedIn names?

Tags: linkedin, title

Is it advisable to include a title (like PhD or Dr.) in a LinkedIn profile name?

Or do recruiters perceive this as pretentious?

Comment: You didn't spend six years in evil medical school to be called 'Mister', thank you very much! Be proud of your achievements.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it advisable to include a title (PhD, Dr.) in a linkedin profile name?

What is the purpose of your LinkedIn profile? Is it to connect with coworkers - how do they know you? Is it by Dr. John Doe? Just John Doe? John Doe, PhD? This will somewhat depend on industry and country too, as some locations/industries place more or less importance on this.

> Or do recruiters perceive this as pretentious?

Like the above, this will vary based on industry and geography.

However, I would suggest leaving it off in - you are going to include your PhD education and publication(s) anyways, so it will be quite clear you have the degree. You can easily include make your degree clear in a personal statement.

Answer (score 3):

If if makes it easier to find you, then it will be useful. It can help if you have a common name that would return thousands of matches. It will also be useful if a recruiter uses the degree as part of the search.

If on the other hand it is honorary and isn't useful for the positions you would be interested in, then it could be seen as pretentious.

The goal of the information on your profile is to allow current and former co-workers to find you, and for recruiters to contact you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't include my title in my LinkedIn profile name and think the majority of LinkedIn members do not do this. I think using your title makes you stand out in the crowd, but it heavily depends on the person reading your resume if they will find it pretentious or not. I'd also keep in mind what jobs your are aiming for. If it is not an academic job, I'd be shy to add the title.